# Using jQuery in two angular.json and modules with Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I have a template that use jQuery in some points, so in my `angular.json` I have the following:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/slimscroll/slimscroll.min.js",
]
```

This work very well, because `slimscroll.min.js` need jquery. But I need jQuery also in a `home.component.ts`, so I installed jQuery from `npm install` and import in Typescript, like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

But in this way I have jQuery imported in two places: `vendor.js` and `scripts.js`. This is not a good practice. If I put jQuery only in Typescript my `slimscroll.min.js` does not work, I got the error:

> jQuery is not defined

So, how can I fix this problem and use jQuery in two places ?

Comment: My answer was wrong. I think the `declare var` answer is the correct approach - just npm install both libraries, and add both to scripts with `"node_modules/..."` in the `angular.json`

Comment: i dot it but jquery continue to show in vendor.js, in my understand jquery should appear only in scripts.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My english is very poor)

You can try this, for solve that problem,in component that use it,

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Good answer. There are some comments about that approach here also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22016#issuecomment-366491200